# Best practice for spinning up container-based (development) environments

Tags: docker, podman

OCI containers are a convenient way to package suitable toolchain for a project so that the development environments are consistent and new project members can start quickly by simply checking out the project and pulling the relevant containers.

- Of course I am not talking about projects that simply need a C++ compiler or Node.JS. I am talking about projects that need specific compiler packages that don't work with newer than Fedora 22, projects with special tools that need to be installed manually into strange places, working on multiple projects that have tools that are not co-installable and such. For this kind of things it is easier to have a container than follow twenty installation steps and then pray the bits left from previous project don't break things for you.

However, starting a container with compiler to build a project requires quite a few options on the [docker](https://www.docker.com/) (or [podman](https://podman.io/)) command-line. Besides the image name, usually:

- mount of the project working directory
- user id (because the container should access the mounted files as the user running it)
- if the tool needs access to some network resources, it might also need

  - some credentials, via environment or otherwise
  - ssh agent socket (mount and environment variable)
- if the build process involves building docker containers

  - docker socket (mount); [buildah](https://buildah.io/) may work without special setup though
- and if is a graphic tool (e.g. IDE)

  - X socket mount and environment variable
  - `--ipc host` to make shared memory work

And then it can get more complicated by other factors. E.g. if the developers are in different departments and don't have access to the same docker repository, their images may be called differently, because [docker](https://www.docker.com/) does not support symbolic names of repositories ([podman](https://podman.io/) does though).

Is there some standard(ish) way to handle these options or is everybody just using ad-hoc wrapper scripts?

Comment: Opinion: Docker is not a good tool for generically packaging desktop-oriented applications or developer tools.  If you need Node, install Node; don’t run through this entire checklist just to get around “installing” the tools you need.

Comment: @DavidMaze, there are two major problems with that: 1. different projects require different versions of the same tools, often ancient ones, and 2. it's, of course, not a single tool, but a list of, say, 20 dependencies, not all of them installable from a package. The docker checklist is waaaay shorter. And keep in mind that a wrapper script will be written once and used by everybody, but the install instructions will be run by somebody every other month.

Comment: FWIW, I use `Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers` extension https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers to put the toolchain needed for a code base in a Docker image.  The extension is still newish, so there is a limit on what kind of Linux Distro can be used for the base of the docker image.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_known-limitations

Comment: @Kin, might make sense to make it an answer—VSCode is quite likely to make this popular quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) to connect the  source code to a Docker container that holds all the tools needed to build the code (e.g `npm` modules, ruby `gems`, `eslint`, Node.JS, `java`).  The container contains all the "tools" used to develop/build/test the source code.

Additionally, you can also put the VSCode extensions into the Docker image to help keep VSCode IDE tools portable as well. 
 https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_managing-extensions

You can provide a Dockerfile in the source code for newcomers to [build the Docker image themselves](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_creating-a-devcontainerjson-file) or attach VSCode to an [existing Docker container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_attaching-to-running-containers).

If you need to run a server inside the Docker container for testing purposes, you can [expose a port on the container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_forwarding-a-port) via VSCode, and start hitting the server inside the container with a browser or `cURL` from the host machine.

Be aware of the [known limitations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_known-limitations) to Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension.  The one that impacts me the most is the [beta support for Alphine Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_system-requirements).  I have often noticed some of the popular Docker Hub images are based on Alphine.

Comment: Their approach is to spin up a persistent container with infinite sleep as the main command, and `exec`ing commands in it, but it probably makes more sense than the transient containers I started using—in particular since some development tools start background processes.

Comment: The remote containers also support docker-compose, which allows anybody who don't want to use vscode to use the container as comfortably from the command-line.

Comment: It's not so much remote, if vscode expects docker to run locally. I tried it with podman with no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.